# How to avoid page breaks between the paragraphs of a description item?

Tags: lists, page-breaking, description

Is there a way of preventing LaTeX from putting page breaks between two paragraphs of a multi-paragraph `\item` in a `description` environment? Preferably without having to put in explicit `\nopagebreak` commands.

(Note: I'm looking for a general solution that will avoid these page breaks altogether, not just a one-off correction for a specific instance. Page breaks between *items* are fine.)

Comment: Use \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} ... \end{minipage} and throw in a \vfil between items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that something like

```
\let\orig@description\description
\def\description{\orig@description
  \let\orig@par\par \def\par{\orig@par\nopagebreak[4]}}
```

works for me. (I could go to `\nopagebreak` – without the optional argument – but there may be situations when the page break may be the better option after all.)

I'm not enthusiastic about the `minipage` idea; the LaTeX source is actually generated by Sphinx, and I don't like to mess with the internals of Sphinx.